# How to Show All data From Database and show Count data From another table

Tags: mysql, count

i have two table. **table1** contain detail of users. **table2** contain all URLs that create by users.

i want to show some data user from **table1** and count all url that create by that user from **table2**.

for example i have data like this:

table1

```
id     username   email            join_date
123    user123    123@email.com    12-11-2018
456    user456    456@email.com    13-11-2018
789    user789    789@email.com    14-11-2018
```

table2

```
id    username   url    date_insert
321   user789    url1   12-12-2018
654   user456    url2   13-12-2018
987   user789    url3   14-12-2018
312   user789    url4   14-12-2018
```

here my code but ofcourse that error.

```
SELECT * COUNT(url.table2) 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.username = table2.username 
ORDER BY table1.join_date DESC
```

i want to show data like this

final result must be like this

```
id(table1)     email(table1)    join_date(table1)  count(url)
----------     --------------   -----------------  -------------
123            789@email.com    14-11-2018         3
456            456@email.com    13-11-2018         1
789            123@email.com    12-11-2018         0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.*, count(table2.url) 
FROM `table1` 
join table2 
ON table2.username=table1.username 
Group By table2.username
```

I would recommend you should use integers as foreign key reference.

Comment: why i have to set int as foreign key?

Comment: Amazing you accepted an answer which doesn't give your required output.

Comment: Integer only take 4 bytes, whereas  a string can be as many bytes as you like. Because of that, an int will always perform better. Unless if you use usernames that are less than 4 characters. Moreover Indexing on int will be faster.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query :-

```
SELECT table1.id,
       table1.username,
       table1.email,
       table1.join_date,
       COUNT(table2.id) AS url
FROM   table1
       LEFT JOIN table2
              ON table2.username = table1.username
GROUP  BY table1.username
ORDER  BY join_date DESC
```